# Submit Button C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, firebug, submit

So I'm developing an APP for windows using the Microsoft Visual 2008 Express edition. I'm new to coding and I'm using a guide for the application I'm using. Now, I want to use GetElementById function on a Submit button. I'm making a program that autofills sweepstakes. It fills in the forms correctly, but fails to Submit the information.
 Firebug shows me this code for the button

```
<input type="submit" class="submit standard-button" value="Submit"/>
```

How do i simulate so it enters the data on the form i filled out? Everything else works out ok, my program just doesn't hit the SUBMIT button on the webpage.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

What you really want to do is get the form and then call submit() on that which will then submit the form with the data.

Comment: True, and to do that: `document.forms[0].submit();` assuming there's only one form in the document..